# Erase not called in std::for_each, but does in range-based for loop?

Tags: c++, c++11

Running the code:

```
for (auto& v : vec)
    v.erase(0, v.find("\n") + 1);
```

Does what is expected: erase everything up until the first "\n" in each element of `vec`.

However, running the code:

```
std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&](std::string v) {
    v.erase(0, v.find("\n") + 1);
});
```

Does not erase anything from any element of `vec`. Making the lambda pass-by-value instead of -reference does not change the result.

Comment: One of them takes `v` by value and one by reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&](std::string v) {
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You are taking the argument by value. You are later only working on a copy, not related to the original object in the container. Change the lambda's argument to a reference. Also remove the capture list (as you are not capturing anything from the current scope!).

Lambda's capture list and argument list are two different beasts. Capturing the current scope's variables is independent from taking parameters by the lambda's `operator()`.

Answer (score 2):

`[&]` is the lambda capture list and specifies how variables from the enclosing scope will be captured in the lambda. It doesn't have anything to do with how `v` will be received. If you want to receive `v` as a reference, you need to make it so:

```
std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&](std::string& v) {
    v.erase(0, v.find("\n") + 1);
});
```

I also can't see any reason for you to capture anything, so make the capture list just `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet

```
for (auto& v : vec)
    v.erase(0, v.find("\n") + 1);
```

is equivalent to

```
for ( std::string& v : vec)
    v.erase(0, v.find("\n") + 1);
```

It means that v is reference to an element of vec. it has nothing common with the ampersand in the lambda expression

```
std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&](std::string v) {
    v.erase(0, v.find("\n") + 1);
});
```

All what you needed is to specify correctly the parameter in the lambda expression the same way as in the range based for statement that is

```
std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), []( std::string &v) {
    v.erase(0, v.find("\n") + 1);
});
```

In your code the  lambda expression gets a copy of the original string.

```
std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [&](std::string v) {
    v.erase(0, v.find("\n") + 1);
});
```

So you change simply the copy.